# Is nikah valid when one is called by his step father's name?

Tags: nikah

My Mom and Dad has been in Nikah for more than 20 years, and my mother has been called with her step father's name since. I recently got to know from a drama serial that Nikah is not valid if spouse(s) is/are called with their step father's name, but I want to confirm if this ruling is true. Prescribe in the light of Koran and hadith. As soon as I come to know, I can persuade my parents to perform Nikah again or not.

Comment: Almost all drama series are corrupt and unreliable, so I advise you not to learn ANYTHING from drama series, especially if it's something related to our religion, cuz media nowadays aim to make us astray. And i've never heard a hadeeth about the matter you asked nor read an aya in the Quraan about it.

Comment: I don't believe in drama serials but the matter is: the drama serial has islamic features. It is a Pakistani drama serial based on a true story of muslim characters. God knows the serial is true or not but I had to confirm, I said, not to believe. BTW, I think you have not been through the whole Koran nor hadith and so can't immediately say that the drama serial is corrupt.

Comment: Yes, i haven't been through all hadeeths, and i didn't say i did, i just said i didn't hear about a hadeeth which mentions what i said, but i've been through the whole Quraan, and such situation wasn't mentioned.

Comment: @AbdelRahmanShamel, I appreciate your advice "You not to learn... to religion" but I think none would instantly learn a religious concept from plays, at least not a normal person. And as far as the second part of your comment is concerned: I tell you that I have also been through the whole Koran but never read something like this but the purpose to post this question on this site was to get answers from experts. When you say "I have not found something related to this topic yet" it sounds silly, doesn't it? You can post when you are sure but when u r not u can help  through other means. :)

Comment: There is a philosophy that says, everything related to dunia matters are halal, except for what was prohibited. But everything related to religion practice is haram, unless what was permitted and ordered to do with. So the reason that I said i never heard any hadiths or Quraan talking about this specific matter, was to say that as long as there were no views about this, then there is no harm doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a [fatwa in Arabic](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=94882), where a man found out that he was adopted and he inherited from his adoptive father and the family of his wife wanted to declare his marriage as invalid as they felt cheated because his family name was false. This is briefly the basis of the fatwa question.

The answer about the marriage was: the nikah is valid but he must change or better correct his name and the family documents because of these ahadith (for example) from [sahih Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/1/126) and [sahih al-Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/61/18) and the Verses ([33:37-40](http://legacy.quran.com/33/37-40)) and ([33:5](http://legacy.quran.com/33/5)) see also the explanation of these Verses in [sunan at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/47/259) or in [sunan an-Nasa-i](http://sunnah.com/nasai/26/28).

So the marriage of your mother is valid, but she has to change her family name and documents for her peace of mind!

And Allah knows best!